# SwashBuckle UI in .Net Core 2.0 showing error

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have just install `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.6.3` and do all the configurations where needed.

when I run the debugger and got the `localhost:65183/swagger/index.html` from by browser it is showing the following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
> at window.onload (index.html:51)
> window.onload @ index.html:51
> load (async)
> (anonymous) @ index.html:46

I have the following folder structure. Here is screenshot of my Project in Visual Studio.

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the problem. I missed a line in the configuration.

This line

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

Comment: Just did basically the exact same thing and ran into the same issue. It's misleading because the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware-1
Just says to add a line like this: `app.UseSwaggerUI();`
But then has a note later that you should add something like what you have, but only mentions it if you want a different endpoint for the UI or want the Swagger 2.0 format. Microsoft should maybe adjust their documentation - I might file a bug about this.